# Unable to install qgis 1.9 on Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I tried to install qgis 1.9 in my laptop. I use Lubuntu 13.04 (64bit).
I used the repository

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly raring main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly raring main
```

and I didn't find any error during the installation.

When I try to start qgis I obtain this message:

> /usr/bin/qgis.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal1.7.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I try

```
sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I obtain those messages:

```
Configurazione di qgis-providers-common (1.9.0+git20130529+e0406e7~raring1)...

/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal1.7.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare qgis-providers-common (--configure):
 il sottoprocesso installato script di post-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 127
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di qgis-providers:
 qgis-providers dipende da qgis-providers-common (= 1.9.0+git20130529+e0406e7~raring1); comunque:
  Il pacchetto qgis-providers-common non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare qgis-providers (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di qgis:
 qgis dipende da qgis-providers (= 1.9.0+git20130529+e0406e7~raring1); comunque:
  Il pacchetto qgis-providers non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare qgis (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di qgis-plugin-globe:
qgis-plugin-globe dipende da qgis (= 1.9.0+git20130529+e0406e7~raring1); comunque:
Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza di un fallimento precedente.
          
Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché è stato raggiunto il valore massimo di MaxReports
         
  Il pacchetto qgis non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass dipende da qgis (= 1.9.0+git20130529+e0406e7~raring1); comunque:
  Il pacchetto qgis non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 qgis-providers-common
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: whats the output of `locate libgdal1.7.0.so.1`? (you might need to do `sudo updatedb` first)

Comment: aptitute is some times smarter then apt-get. Try `sudo aptitute dist-upgrade` to resolve any conflicts

Comment: This question is closed because the problem was caused by a temporary bug in the development version which has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some help in searching for the tags related to qgis and ubuntu/centos here. The first message is related to a missing gdal installation (or at least the installer cannot find it). 
Install the necessary plugins and go to the configure script to set the path to gdal.

You try to install qgis with grass support but do not have grass installed. The message tells you to install the related packages prior to compiling qgis.

Comment: I solved. I think it was a bug and the guys of QGIS fixed it. Thank you so much